# Variables in memory on server once session times out

Tags: asp.net, session, garbage-collection

I've created a web site that is used mainly to do reporting on multiple locations and e-mail reports and things like that. Since its dealing with a lot of information I've set it up so it grabs a bunch of information at one time then I go through it with linq and filter it however I need to. When someone actually clicks the logout button then the variables are released and cleaned up.

My questiion is what happens to those variables if the user never actually clicks logout and either lets the session timeout or x's out of the web browser they are using?

If the variables aren't released how do people normally handle that?

Thanks, 
Mike

Comment: Are you saying that this data is stored in session state? If so, have you considered using application state or caching instead?

Comment: My lack of familiarity with caching was causing weird behavior when one browser was used to log into the site for multiple different "customers." As of right now all caching is disabled I believe and I'm basically storing a number in the session that points to an array variable that is holding the information for the user that "owns" the pointer in their session. It isn't a very good method of keeping track of who is who. Most definitely not the best way to do that but I wrote it before I did much research on authentication methods and changing it now would be a huge headache.

Comment: Is the information user-specific in any way, or do all users work off of the same result set?

Comment: There are user specific variables in that there is an array of 1000 objects all set to nothing unless a user logs in and gets an ID that I set to the milliseconds of when the login request happens and is stored in their session. Its a small scale website, if 50 people log in at the same time then it would raise some eyebrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've described it, it sounds like the best solution is to store the data in cache, so that you can reference it whenever you need to.

Here is a simple example of how to cache a DataSet object:

```
DataSet ds = RetrieveLotsOfData();
Cache["MyDataSet"] = ds;
```

Once the data is stored in cache, you can reference it anywhere like this:

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["MyDataSet"];
```

See this article for an overview of cache management in ASP.NET:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachemanagementinaspnet.aspx

Comment: [Caching overview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachemanagementinaspnet.aspx) - Found this helpful also.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien: Thanks. I've updated my answer to include the link you provided. It might help someone else in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

If your session times out (it will eventually) then your server will release it's reference to the `Session` object which holds the reference to the object that you're storing in the `SessionState`. When there's no reference left for an object it's automatically garbage collected when the garbage collector is run. By the way, if your user clicks `logout` it doesn't mean the objects are cleared immediately but just that the objects are made available for garbage collection. This way you're not really sure when they will be collected but this allows the garbage collection process to only run if needed and do some extra cleaning when your application is not under heavy load.